# How to provide canonical URL with Django HttpResponseRedirect?

Tags: django, httpresponse

This question is very similar to one I just asked [href: Can I get Google search results to use/display the final redirect url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728433/href-can-i-get-google-search-results-to-use-display-the-final-redirect-url), but now the question is specific to Django.

My site has webpage urls that use the following format:

```
www.mysite.com/id/pretty_title
```

The front page links to these pages, but the href  actually contains some parameters:

```
 www.mysite.com/id/?some_ugly_parameters_to_let_me_know_what_search_it_is_from
```

This then redirects to

```
www.mysite.com/id/pretty_title
```

which shows the page.

**My issue is that** Google's search results show the link to the page as the ugly url instead of the pretty redirected one.

What I have learned is that I need to provide a canonical link. But how can I do this when the ugly url page never really exists, at least not as one that I have written?

What happens server side is that the view of the ugly url does a redirect:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(pretty_url)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just put it as part of the HTML returned from the Django template, in the `<head>` section.
Do you have a `base.html` in your Django? You can setup a `{% block %}` as a placeholder for the canonical URL and then set that value in each individual page that `{% extends base.html %}`

base.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="canonical" href="{% block canonical_url %}{% endblock %}">
</head>
...
```

Comment: This html page is displayed by pretty_url. Or does it also 'count' as being displayed by the ugly_url since it redirects to this?

Comment: In your Django there should be only one view that returns that unique content, all you have to do is get the canonical tag into the HTML of that one view. Wether the content from that view is accessible through one or another URL is not important.

Answer (score 11):

I think this is the correct built template tag that you're looking for. 
    {{ request.build_absolute_uri }}

Comment: For some reason, `build_absolute_uri` gives me the http scheme even when the whole website is on https. I'm on Django 1.6 (fairly old, but it's what we've got at the moment).

Comment: @PritishC <link rel="canonical" href="https://{{ request.get_host }}{{ request.get_full_path }}">

Answer (score 3):

A lot of these proposed solutions have issues if (1) you want your `www` subdomain to be the canonical one and (2) there are URL params in the request path.

I would actually propose to hard code it in the base template and append `request.path`.

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com{{ request.path }}">
```

If you do end up wanting to use `build_absolute_uri`, I would do it as follows in your view (or you could create a template function):

```py
canonical_url = request.build_absolute_uri(request.path)
```

Calling `build_absolute_uri()` without an argument will call `request.get_full_path()` and append that to your domain.  If a user finds your site via `https://www.example.com/?param=123`, your canonical URL will include that param.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @getup8 that the proposed solutions will cause issues. If the URL that was used to access the page is fetched programmatically and that URL is not the canonical one, a non-canonical URL will be declared as canonical. That's not what you want.

What I do instead is have Django fetch the URL of the view, like so:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com{% url 'view_name' %}">
```

Thus ignoring whatever path the user actually used, and always using the standard, base view URL as the canonical one. Yes, this means naming the view in each page, but is still better than hardcoding the URLs.